# ¿Cómo se puede añadir correctamente 3 celdas de 3 columnas de una tabla a otra tabla en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, join, tablas

La siguiente query:

```
SELECT * FROM dapp.credentials WHERE id = ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM dapp.credentials )
```

Trae la siguiente fila:

```
|  id  | email          | password       | first_name | member_type | validated |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  5000|perkins@drit.com|1234perkins     |Mickey      | regular     |1          |
```

Ahora, esta otra query:

```
SELECT cellphone, address, zipcode FROM dapp.members
WHERE user_id = ( SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM dapp.members )
```

Trae esta otra fila:

```
| cellphone     | address             | zipcode | 
-------------------------------------------------
| (787)-142-6952|4108 Wheeler Ridge Dr|99563    |
```

¿Cómo podría entonces crear una query que traiga la siguiente información?

```
|  id  | email          | password       | first_name | member_type | validated || cellphone     | address             | zipcode | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  5000|perkins@drit.com|1234perkins     |Mickey      | regular     |1          || (787)-142-6952|4108 Wheeler Ridge Dr|99563    |
```

Intenté usar esta query:

```
SELECT * FROM dapp.credentials WHERE id = ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM dapp.credentials )
JOIN
(SELECT cellphone, address, zipcode FROM dapp.members
WHERE user_id = ( SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM dapp.members ))
```

Pero obtuve el siguiente error:

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
> the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'JOIN (SELECT cellphone, address, zipcode FROM
> dapp.members WHERE user_id = ( S' at line 2

¿Puedo saber en que me equivoqué con mi última query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te has liado demasiado con las sub-consultas, y eso nubla el horizonte cuando la consulta se hace un poquito más compleja.

Por ejemplo, el primer resultado pudo haberse obtenido con esto simplemente:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dapp.credentials 
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

La misma simplicidad podemos aplicar al `JOIN` que quieres operar:

```
SELECT 
    c.id,
    c.email,
    c.password,
    c.first_name,
    c.member_type,
    c.validated,
    m.cellphone, 
    m.address, 
    m.zipcode
FROM dapp.credentials AS c 
INNER JOIN dapp.members AS m ON c.id=m.user_id
ORDER BY c.id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Oh, entonces así es como funciona, ¡gracias! Sí no te molesta, ¿podrías decirme para que sirve la última sentencia de `ORDER BY c.id DESC LIMIT 1;` ? Me refiero a ¿por qué se usa ese `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: @NoahVerner esto `ORDER BY c.id DESC` significa que ordene de forma DESCendente por el `id` de la tabla cuyo alias es `c`, o sea, la tabla `credentials`  y el `LIMIT 1` significa que LIMITe la cantidad de filas a 1. Al ver esto en tu consulta original: `WHERE id = ( SELECT MAX(id)` se interpreta que quieres el registro con el mayor `id`, pues eso es lo que hace precisamente la instrucción `ORDER BY c.id DESC LIMIT 1;` si por ejemplo si te interesan todos los registros, quitas el `LIMIT 1` y obtendrías todos los registros.